# Perl set file handle based on command line args

Tags: perl, unix, command-line, stdin, filehandler

I want to read from the default input if data is piped in or a file is provided, but if nothing is given I would like to supply a default for `while(<>)` to execute on.

Pseudocode:

```
if(!<>){
  <> = system("ls | ./example.pl");
}

while(<>){
...
...
...
}
```

Comment: What part of your implementation is tripping you up?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be valid. I want to set <>. Also the test (`if(!<>)`) doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @Chris right, none of that is really sensible. `<>` is an operator that reads from a file. You can't set it, and doing `if(!<>)` reads a line from somewhere and tests whether *that line* is true or false.

Comment: @hobbs hence the "Pseudocode" prompt. I know that is incorrect and am asking how to do the equivalent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "if data is piped in" makes things difficult. It's easy to say

```
if (!@ARGV) {
    @ARGV = ("somedefault");
}

while (<>) {
    ...
}
```

which will operate on "somedefault" if no filenames are given on the commandline — but that means you'll never get the Perl default of reading from stdin if there aren't any filenames on the commandline.

One possible compromise is to use the [-t operator](http://p3rl.org/-X) to guess whether stdin is a terminal:

```
if (!@ARGV && -t STDIN) {
    @ARGV = ("somedefault");
}
```

Which will use "somedefault" if there are no filenames on the commandline *and* stdin is attached to a terminal, but it will use stdin if there are no filenames and stdin is redirected from a file or a pipe. This is a little magical (maybe annoyingly so), but does what you asked for.

Comment: When I try that, substituting `(some default)` with `system("ls")` the terminal runs forever. Am I piping it in wrong? I also tried "ls | ./ctime" but that seems infinitely recursive.

Comment: Neither of those makes sense. `"ls|"` might make sense.

Answer (score 4):

How about trying to read from `<>`, and then falling back to your default if nothing was read?

```
while (my $line = <>)
{
     do_stuff($line);
}

# if no lines were read, fall back to default data source
if (not $.)
{
     while (my $line = <SOMETHING_ELSE>)
     {
          do_stuff($line);
     }
}
```

You can read about the `$.` variable [here, at perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) - it indicates the "current" line number of the most recent filehandle read from. If it is undefined, there was nothing to read from `<>`.